# Select statement to retrieve code of the IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 columns (`id_org`, `code_org`, `id_root_org`) in table `org`. The `id_root_org` specifies the top most org of an org in the table.

```
org 1 (id_org=1, id_root_org = 1 since it is its own root)
  --org 2 (id_org=2, id_root_org = 1)
  --org 3 (id_org=3, id_root_org = 1)
    --org 3.1 (id_org=3.1, id_root_org = 1)
```

How can I retrieve the code of all the root organizations?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a root is a record where the `id_root_org = id_org`. To get the `code_org` of that rows you can use a simple `SELECT`.

```
SELECT code_org
       FROM elbat
       WHERE id_root_org = id_org;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want the list of ID_ROOT_ORG?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_ROOT_ORG
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```